Passing an object in a form to JSP
I encountered the following problem, I have two classes Student and Faculty, and Student has a faculty field. And the question is: how can I pass exactly an object in this form to the faculty field of an object of the Student class?
P. S. model attribute "faculties" contains a list of objects of all types of faculties.
    <%--@elvariable id="student" type="org.oskirko.spring.Models.Entities.Student"--%>
    <form:form action="/add_new_student" modelAttribute="student">
        Name: <form:input path="name"/>
        <br><br>
        Surname: <form:input path="surname"/>
        <br><br>
        Avg. grade <form:input path="averageGrade"/>
        <br><br>
        Faculty
        <form:select path="faculty">
            <%--@elvariable id="faculties" type="java.util.List"--%>
            <form:options items="${faculties}" itemLabel="name" itemValue="id"/>
        </form:select>

        <input type="submit" value="Add">
    </form:form>

I tried to simply pass the list of faculty names initially, but if I select a line from select, a new object will be created with the name of the faculty that I selected (as I understand this due to parameter binding), and I need the new object not to be created but for the students the existing faculty was consolidated.

you define the itemValue as id , so it seems like  changing the corresponding select path as faculty.id  is more reasonable. code snippet like following .
<form:select path="faculty.id">
    <%--@elvariable id="faculties" type="java.util.List"--%>
    <form:options items="${faculties}" itemLabel="name" itemValue="id"/>
</form:select>


Setting the path to faculity.id, like Peng said, will selected faculty object instead of just its name.
You need to retrieve the Faculty object based on this ID and set it to the faculty property of the student object.
